# Arrays in Bash and running stat against each directory

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, stat

I have an unknown set of files/folders (I keep having to add to the list) that I need to check for owner and permissions.  So I pieced together

```
dirs=(/mnt /mnt/data /mnt/data/1.txt)
for i in $(dirs[@]}; do
stat -c "%U:$G" ${dirs[$i]}
done
```

However, I receive a syntax error 'operand expected (error token is "/mnt"'

point me in the right direction please

Comment: `$(dirs[@])` is not an array reference at all; it needs to be `"${dirs[@]}"` -- note the curly braces instead of parens. (The quotes are also necessary for correct operation, but that's a smaller bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in ${dirs[@]}` isn't iterating the indices of the array, but the actual contents.

Try this:

```
dirs=(/mnt /mnt/data /mnt/data/1.txt)
for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
stat -c "%U:$G" "$i"
done
```

**EDIT** With cleaner variable names per glennjackman's suggestion:

```
paths=(/mnt /mnt/data /mnt/data/1.txt)
for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
stat -c "%U:$G" "$path"
done
```

Comment: For clarity, perhaps a more descriptive variable name: `for dir in "${dirs[@]}" ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Fair, `dirs` is also not a great name for the array since the last element appears to be a file. I'll edit and clean a bit.

Comment: Hmm, `paths` maybe

Comment: I assume this is more of a "allowing someone to read your code later easily" justification for dirs v. paths?  I meant logistically the word is irrelevant, right?

Comment: @Nathan yes the names are just names, they can be whatever you want. Good names can improve clarity though, for example I wonder if you tried to use `i` as an index in the beginning because that's a typical index variable name in a loop. Or even if you had other reasons, someone reading your code in the future could make that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @tjm3772's answer: if you want to iterate over the array's *indices*:

```bash
for idx in "${!dirs[@]}"
# ............^
do
  stat -c "%U:$G" "${dirs[i]}"
done
```

See [6.7 Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) in the manual